# 'MatplotlibDeprecationWarning' - Warning when trying to plot histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to use `matplotlib` to plot a histogram but keep running into this error:

`MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The resize_event function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use callbacks.process('resize_event', ResizeEvent(...)) instead.`

Here's my code; feedback on how I can clean up the logical expressions also welcome.

```
lower_quartile = df['2020 Population'].quantile(0.25)
mid_quartile = df['2020 Population'].quantile(0.5)
upper_quartile = df['2020 Population'].quantile(0.75)

new_data = df.loc[df['2020 Population'] > lower_quartile]

final_2020_range = new_data.loc[df['2020 Population'] < upper_quartile]

check = final_2020_range['2020 Population']

plt.hist(check)
```

Comment: Seems to be a known issue that'll be fixed in v3.6.1, see [github Bug: resize_event deprecation warnings when creating figure on macOS with version 3.6.0](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23921)

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you can find your answer here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23921

In short: it's a bug, and it will be corrected in 3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue,
I found a work-around:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Error will still be there, but now you can see plots.